# Node google api not returning 'request' object

Tags: node.js, google-api

I am trying to use the [node google api](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) to download some excel files. I found [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#examples) example and am not seeing the same results.

When running similar code I am getting `Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined`:

```
var output = fs.createWriteStream("./output/accounts/2016/" + file.name);

var test = drive.files.get({
  fileId: file.gID,
  alt: 'media'
}).pipe(output);
```

I tried to log the returned value of the get and am just getting `undefined`:

```
var output = fs.createWriteStream("./output/accounts/2016/" + file.name);

var test = drive.files.get({
  fileId: file.gID,
  alt: 'media'
});

console.log(test);
```

I can get the text of the file using a callback format. The code below runs and prints out a bunch of special characters due to the excel format. Saving using `fs.writeFile(...)` and then opening with excel does not result in the correct formatting, I still have special characters everywhere and all the data is in column A.

```
var test = drive.files.get({
  fileId: file.gID,
  alt: 'media'
}, function (err, contents) {
    console.log(contents);
});
```

Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: You might mention which module you're using to access the API.

Comment: Sorry about that, added a link. It is the google api node client (by google)

Comment: What version of the `googleapis` module do you have installed (`npm ls googleapis`)?

Comment: it is version `2.1.7`. However I did find a solution and have answered the question below

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I found some old issues on the github related to this. I guess the updating to OAuth2 broke refreshing tokens, and the token needs to be refreshed manually in order to get the Response object returned.

Source: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/381

Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(...);
jwtClient.refreshAccessToken(function(err, tokens) {
  var test = drive.files.get({
    fileId: googleFileId,
    alt: 'media'
  }).on('end', function() {
    finished.call();
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    process.exit(err);
  }).pipe(output);
});
```